# How to produce a settings dialog (and save the values)

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

These are my first steps with the Firefox AddOn SDK. What I'm trying to create is a simple 'settings dialogue'. I thought about a html page containing forms for the values and a submit button. Following the first mozilla tutorials I created a widget:

```
var widget = require('widget').Widget({
  label: 'Settings',
  id: 'settings',
  //panel: text_entry
  contentURL: data.url('images/stgfavicon.ico'),
  contentScriptFile: data.url('scripts/submit.js'),
  onClick: function() {
    tabs.open(data.url('forms/settings.html'));
  }
});
```

But since *settings.js* is not the contentScriptFile I got no communication between *settings.html* and *settings.js*. Is it possible to get this done without some (complex looking) messaging system? And how to save the values best? A JSON file?
Some links/examples/API names would help me a lot. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're trying to attach your script to the widget (which is not an HTML file). You need to attach it to the actual html file after the tab opens.

```
tabs.open({
    url: data.url('forms/settings.html'),
    onOpen: function onOpen(tab) {
        tab.attach({ contentScriptFile: data.url('scripts/submit.js'); });
    }
});
```

I haven't tested that out so there may be an error.

You should also look at the simple-prefs module if these are settings that aren't going to be adjusted frequently.

Comment: If simple-prefs doesn't work for storage, there is also simple-storage: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/packages/addon-kit/simple-storage.html